# PHP files are not executed on Apache using LAMP

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I'm new to Ubuntu, I have Ubuntu 16.04, and I just installed LAMP using this guide https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/
I've created testphp.php file inside /var/www/html
The file contains the lines:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

However, when I browse localhost/testphp.php, this is what I see:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozaUg.jpg)

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you put your webserver configuration?

Comment: You mean the apache.conf file?

Comment: @MohammadSadeghAlirezaie